# Azure DevOps Server - CI - Database Unit test

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, azure-devops-server-2019

I have an on-premises Azure DevOps Server and have a VS2019 Solution that contains a database project (using SSDT).   I have added some database unit tests to the solution and these run through correctly.

I have created a build pipeline for the database solution which builds the database project.  I now want to add a task to the pipeline to execute the unit tests.  The default task finds the unit tests in the solution and tries to execute them - however it is failing with the a SQL connection error '*The server was not found or was not accessible*'.

The unit test project has an app.settings which has two connection strings to the same host (ExecutionContext and PrivilegedContext) - these connect using integrated security.

I have two questions:

1) How do I determine which host it is trying to connect to? or is there a variable I need to define?

2) In Azure DevOps server - how do I specify the account to run the unit tests under (so it can connect to the appropriate database server)?

Comment: What have you tried so far to fix the problem?

Comment: A bit of a fudge.  After working out what the two contexts do, I have modified the app.config to point to the correct server (currently my dev machine) so 1) is resolved.  However, for 2) I had to give the build server service account access to by database server which is not allowed when I move to the proper test environment. I need to run the build process or the testing process under a different domain account.